# How to speedup jquery mobile / phonegap?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a small web app. Seven pages, 3.6 KB index.html and 855.5 KB total. The only odd thing i have is a database (~500kb) in Javascript with many lines like:

```
$.data(db,'Aarstraße',['34236:1','34246:2','34270:4','34290:6',...]);
```

I tested it on iPod/iPhone and Android (HTC Magic) and it is very slow:

Startup

- iPhone: 14 seconds
- Android: 21 seconds

Simple page transition (slide)

- iPhone: 3-4 seconds
- Android: 4-6 seconds

How can I make this fast?

I already removed the [box shadow](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/a-fix-for-low-android-performance-remove-box-shadow).

**Update**

I remove the database leaving 444.7KB page total. Now it runs faster on Android. Around the same as one iPhone. It still feels very slow.

**Update 2**

After [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004308/jquery-mobile-transitions-judder-on-android/9004548), I switched to the [latest jquery mobile build](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/04/16/latest/). It improved the page transitions for slow Android devices to ~2 seconds per transition. Release of Version 1.1 will be [mid/late February](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/01/10/upcoming-releases-1-0-1-1-1-and-beyond/).

Comment: javascript database?? you should consider to only serve data as needed.

Comment: @stian.net How? It contains only 1800 lines.

Comment: 500kb is pretty much for a mobile application..

Comment: I removed the db and asked for [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004140/phonegap-local-store) but it is still slow.

Comment: @PiTheNumber - nice of you linking through to your follow up questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few things you can do:

1. [Get to deviceready faster](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/12/on-first-day-of-phonegapping-get-to.html).
2. Minimize your JS code using [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)
3. Move your script tags to the bottom of the body tag.

As you've already mentioned you've moved the database out of the equation which was probably taking a bulk of the time on startup.

Answer (score 5):

What do you do with jQuery-mobile? It's performance is very poor, you should never call it on elements bigger that required. See [this discussion about jquery-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867544/whats-the-fastest-way-to-load-a-large-nested-list-in-jquery-mobile) for details. It is doing very large number of DOM search operations because it works by modifying the DOM tree. As for my tests, it works too slow even on desktop browser.

Comment: So the solution is not to use jQuery, hm... ok

Comment: Using jQuery is fine, jQuery-mobile specifically is considered by some to react poorly with PhoneGap.  Here's a discussion of why: http://apachecordova.blogspot.com/2012/11/who-is-murdering-phonegap-its-jquery.html

Comment: By bigger than required, I've meant for example, not rendering the whole list if only a part of it will be shown. You don't want to show to the user a dropdown that has 100 or more positions! If you want, please unwant it, it will scroll their fingers to the bone!

Answer (score 4):

Try without transitions. Even with jQuery 1.1, the page transitions can be really flickery and slow on an iPhone.

To drop page transitions globally, just add the following to jqm.glocal.config.js

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.defaultPageTransition="none"
});
```