# Phonegap store local db

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a bulk of data in my app. I need it in case the app runs offline.

Currently I have it in a data.js file and use the [jQuery data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function to manage it. There are 1800 lines like this. ~500kb in total.

```
$.data(db,'Aarstraße',['34236:1','34246:2','34270:4','34290:6',...]);
```

Is there a better way to store this data?

My main concern is performance. Not to query some data but the app performance in total like RAM usage and startup time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is for you to pre-populate a SQLite DB and on application startup copy the DB to the correct location so your app can access it. There is a good blog post on this topic at:

http://gauravstomar.blogspot.com/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+GauravSTomarBootstrappingIntelligence+%28Gaurav+S+Tomar+%3A+Bootstrapping+Intelligence%29

Comment: Follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061112/access-pre-populate-sql-lite-db-in-phonegap