# Access pre-populate SQL Lite DB in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I created a pre-populate SQL Lite DB an added it to my app as described in my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004140/phonegap-store-local-db).

Now, how can I use this DB?

I guess I need to use `openDatabase` but how do i make it open my DB in /assets/data.db?

I tried this:

```
        var shortName = 'data'; 
        var version = '1.0'; 
        var displayName = 'data'; 
        var maxSize = 65535;

        var db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize); 

        function errorHandler(transaction, error)
        {
            // error.message is a human-readable string.
            // error.code is a numeric error code
            alert('DB Error: '+error.message+' (Code '+error.code+')');
        }

        db.transaction(
            function(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('SELECT street, numbers FROM streets', [], function(tx, results) {
                    // do some more stuff
                    alert("My first database query finished executing!");
                }, errorHandler);
            }
        );
```

But get `sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: streets`.

I used the [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) to make sure the table exists. BTW: I don't have a 0000000000000001.db file.

Comment: I could not solve this and moved the database to a webserver and query it over ajax. Anyway, I accepted the only answer to close the topic.

Comment: Try my answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190066/how-to-read-the-data-from-sqlite3-in-javascript-in-phonegap-application-for-ipho/9193511#9193511

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the Java code from http://gauravstomar.blogspot.com/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+GauravSTomarBootstrappingIntelligence+%28Gaurav+S+Tomar+%3A+Bootstrapping+Intelligence%29 to copy your DB from the assets folder to the correct folder on your device?

Comment: I did. I only removed the line to copy 0000000000000001.db.