# How to read the data from sqlite3 in javascript in phonegap application for iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova, sqlite

I am working on an application in phonegap for iphone, where i have a database in sqlite3 which contains values of latitudes and longitudes and corresponding there area names. I have copied the sqlite data file within the application. I need to fetch the data from the sqlite and display the data in the table in the view, so how to fetch the data in the javascript?

Comment: have to gone through this http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Comment: @InderKumarRathore, I gone through that URL which you gave, and coded in the same way they had explained in it,but there is no output from that, even alert is  not showing.

Answer (score 0):

@PiTheNumber try that code

```
         var arr = new Array(); 
        // Wait for PhoneGap to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // Populate the database 
        //
        function populateDB(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (3, "First row")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (4, "Second row")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (5, "First row")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (6, "Second row")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (7, "First row")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (8, "Second row")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (9, "First row")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (10, "Second row")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (11, "First row")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (12, "Second row")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (13, "First row")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (14, "Second row")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (15, "First row")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (16, "Second row")');
        }



        // Query the database
        //
        function queryDB(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
        }

        // Query the success callback
        //
        function querySuccess(tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
            for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            $('#home').append('<li><a href="#artists">'+results.rows.item(i).data+'</a></li>');



            }
            console.log("aaa"+arr+"aaa"); 

        }

        // Transaction error callback
        //
        function errorCB(err) {
            console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
        }

        // Transaction success callback
        //
        function successCB() {
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
            db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
        }

        // PhoneGap is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
            db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

@shasha replace the refrence of phonegap.js" file with phonegap-1.4.1.js

(if u are using 1.4.1 version of phone gap) it will work.

@InderKumarRathore dude i just figured it out
this was my table view or ur can say list view

```
        <body>
            <div class="toolbar">
                <h1 id="pageTitle"></h1>
                <a id="backButton" class="button" href="#"></a>
                <a class="button" href="#searchForm">Search</a>
            </div>

            <ul id="home" title="Music" selected="true">
                <li><a href="#artists">Artists</a></li>
                <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="stats.gtpl">Stats</a></li>
                <li><a href="#themes">Theme Switcher</a></li>
                <li><a href="#iui-cache-panel">HTML5 WebApp Cache</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://code.google.com/p/iui/" target="_self">About</a></li>
                <li>Nothing</li>
            </ul>    </body>
```

and in Java script use this code

```
$('#home').append('<li>'+data+'</li>');
```

data will the the variable u want to use

hope it worked it does  for me... !!!!

Cheers

Comment: How is this related to sqlite? I just see some html and a line jquery code.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that.... the data in the JS file was from the database.