# SQLite and iPad connection not done

Tags: objective-c, ipad, sqlite, connection, insert-update

I have made one sample project which can add and edit records from SQLite database through simulator..
But when I connect my app with iPad and run it.
It will not connect the app with sqlite database and finally my add and edit functionality is not working.
null values are being passed when i try to fetch data.
I have tried a lot to resolve this problem.
But can't find the reason why it's happening.
Please help me out.

Comment: Is the database present and populated on the real device?

Comment: @DonalFellows-yes...The view is appeared with all controls on real device...

Comment: Can you please post some code so that we can make out where the problem lies.

Comment: @ParthBhatt -I have solved that problem...Thanks

Comment: @KhushbuShah: Thats nice, but in that case you should post your answer as an Answer and Accept it. So it no longer appears as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I found is...

when I was inserting values in the SQLite database throgh my iPad devide,new instance of database is created in ipad.

Now when I insert data through iPad data was being stored in that ipad's database only...

While I was checking in my SQL database stored in my drive in PC. That was wrong.

So when I wanted to fetch the data for some ID it won't get the detail as it is not there in my device's database.

It was database path problem..Thanks to all

Comment: I will take care about such things

Answer (score 0):

see if u have imported the Database in the ipad project. and do mention whether u are using Native language or cross platform development.

for Phonegap Try my answer from here :

[How to read the data from sqlite3 in javascript in phonegap application for iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190066/how-to-read-the-data-from-sqlite3-in-javascript-in-phonegap-application-for-ipho/9211227#9211227)

Comment: In iPad simulator it is working but in iPad device it is not working.

Comment: well it will be difficult to tell without seeing the code. the only thing i could think of is ur Ipad device need to be upgraded with ios5.

Comment: No..Other projects are working properly on same plateform...and the issue is not concern with code i think...because that code is working properly in simulator..