# How to open an existing WebSQL database?

Tags: html, cordova, web-sql

I'm building an HTML5/Phonegap mobile application and I want to use an existing SQLite database through WebSQL.
By an "existing" database I mean I had already created the db.sqlite file outside of the app. I did this because there are several tables and it is pre-populated with some data.
What I wanna do is copy this db file into my project and be able to open it with Javascript just like this:

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
```

It seems like this command only creates a new db or opens an existing db that was created with this command.
If it's possible to open a DB that was created outside my app, how can I open it? How can I set the db path, filename, etc?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9066600/41679

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access pre-populate SQL Lite DB in Phonegap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061112/access-pre-populate-sql-lite-db-in-phonegap)

Comment: thanks... a previous search did not bring me this question.

Comment: @Ecil is it works for you even i have the same problem..i'm unable to retrieving the data from database

Answer (score 0):

WebSQl has that gotcha. Open database without version and then do version migration, eg:

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

if (db.version != '1.0) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Can you include the line to migrate the version too?  and are we doing  this here because we need sqlite3?  After the db is migrated up to - I assume sqlite3  (right?) - then how do we open or access the externally created sqlite file?  I think if you could answer these additional questions, then I will try it out. If it works, I'll vote your answer up.

Comment: For data population see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061112/access-pre-populate-sql-lite-db-in-phonegap Migration are similar to sqlite3 except there is not `ALTER TABLE` in websql. You can still use `DELETE COLUMN, ADD COLUMN`, etc. Use `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` in these extreme migration case.