# jQuery-mobile transitions judder on Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Even in the emulator (Android 2.2) a page transition runs like this:

- touch
- some delay...
- slide to new page
- new page full visible, but hides instantly
- showing old page again
- some short delay...
- finally the new page

It is a big flickering and looks very broken.

Is that normal? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's normal. In fact this [blog post](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/01/10/upcoming-releases-1-0-1-1-1-and-beyond/) about what to expect in jQuery Mobile 1.1 directly references that poor performance of transitions on Android. Looks like you will be stuck with it until the next release. I've seen the issue you talk about as well.

Comment: ah nice. I tried the [latest build](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/04/16/latest/). Page transitions still flickering a little but it does not look so bad and is much faster.

Comment: Yeah, I'm building a test app with PG Android and jQuery Mobile so I can talk the talk with other folks using jqm.

Comment: Working with jquery mobile 1.1 and current git master here, and seeing the exact same problem. It might be related to how the app deals with events...