# jquery mobile 1.4 + phonegap, how to improve transitions and overall performance

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

My Jquery Mobile 1.4 + Phonegap 3.3 app is sluggish.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003393/how-to-speedup-jquery-mobile-phonegap), I already took some measures:

-I am not doing anything int `onload`, but everything in `deviceready`.

-I have moved my script tags to the bottom of the body tag.

-I have not minified my js yet, because it sort of impractical to develop like this.
-I do this for Android:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1) {
        $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
        $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
    }
```

-I have removed `box-shadow` in css.
-I am not sure about this because it doesn't seem to support every platform :https://github.com/ccoenraets/PageSlider

Is there anything else to do ?

Comment: What devices are we talking about? I see android in the code but is it android 2.3 or 4.4? iOS or Windows Phone support?

Comment: @DickvandenBrink on iOS everything is a bit smoother, but my main problem is on android 2.3. Though it is not brilliant on android 4.+

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, I also have these problems.
So I find some tips

- You can use Velocity.js, for my part, I see a net improvement of
  transitions
- You can change the time of css transformation in the css file JQM,
  100ms it's okay
- If you use listview you can also write in personal css, the JQM
  listviews are really too slow
- Avoid a large number of images (compressed and cached) or sprites
- For less important js scripts, use defer
- If you use Ajax and PHP, prepare all requests
- Uses inline css for small style
- Minify also HTML